# IOS Date Formatting ISSUE

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

i have date like this format

"lastUpdatedTime": "2016-09-03 02:01 AM",

I have to format like `03 Sep 2016 02:01 am`

I have tried with `dateFormatter`

Its not working

```
 NSString *lastUpdatedTime = [JSONResultDict valueForKey:@"lastUpdatedTime"];

 NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
 NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:lastUpdatedTime];
```

but yourDate is nil

Comment: try date format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"

Comment: tried but it gives wrong value, i think some time zone issue

Comment: it gives 2016 09 02 02:01 am

Comment: try below code.

Comment: You need at least two date formats, one for input (string->date) and one for output (date->string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a` format for 12 Hour time formate you need to use `hh` instead of `HH`.

```
NSString *lastUpdatedTime = [JSONResultDict valueForKey:@"lastUpdatedTime"];
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a";
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:lastUpdatedTime];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a";
NSString *formttedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: yourDate];
NSLog(@"%@",formttedDate);
```

**Output**

```
03 Sep 2016 02:01 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
  NSString *lastUpdatedTime = [JSONResultDict valueForKey:@"lastUpdatedTime"];

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a";
    NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:lastUpdatedTime];
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a";

    [dateFormatter setAMSymbol:@"am"];
    [dateFormatter setPMSymbol:@"pm"];

    NSString *newDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: yourDate];


    NSLog( @"Date  : %@", newDate );

Output : Date  : 03 Sep 2016 12:01 am
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
NSString *lastUpdatedTime = [JSONResultDict valueForKey:@"lastUpdatedTime"];
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a";
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:lastUpdatedTime];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a";
NSLog(@"Date: %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a slightly different date format and change it to the format you want as follows:

```
NSString *lastUpdatedTime = [JSONResultDict valueForKey:@"lastUpdatedTime"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a";
NSDate * yourDate = [formatter dateFromString:lastUpdatedTime];
formatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a";
NSLog(@"my date is: %@",[formatter stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```